# App for bicycle navigation in Prague?

Tags: bicycles, czech-republic, prague, gps-navigation

I usually use Google Maps for navigation in places I travel to. But Google Maps has no bike navigation for routes in Prague, only for going by car and on foot.

Bike lanes seem to be well hidden in Prague and a lot of roads are not usable with bike.

What is a good alternative to Google Maps for bicycle navigation in Prague on the smartphone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use [mapy.cz](https://mapy.cz/). It supports bike navigation in the whole of Czechia, including Prague. It also has [apps for Android, iOS and Windows Phone](https://mapy.cz/?mobilepromo=1).

Unfortunately, the website seems to be Czech language-only. At least the Android app is (mostly) translated to English, though.

The Android app also supports downloading the map, which can be useful for example if you have access to a wi-fi, but don't have a data plan.

Comment: I have tested the android version and it's okay. Not as comfortable as Google Maps, but there doesn't seem to be a better alternative at the moment.

Comment: Some more experience: It generally chooses bike good routes in Prague, but you need to be careful with the target. For example when I chose the Prague main station as a target, it took me up a hill at the back side of the station where there is actually no entry. So verify the target is sensible before following the route.

Comment: How could you have known there is no entry there before getting there?

Answer (score 5):

[Na kole Prahou](https://nakoleprahou.cz/pick/) (iOS/Android) is a bicycle navigation app from the city of Prague that is specifically designed for that purpose: finding the most bike friendly or fastest route (with or without bike sharing integration), filtering on traffic or elevation profile.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your post, Florian! Are you affiliated with Na kole Prahou?

Comment: No :) I remember having used it, it's been a while now...